# Docker python error. urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>

Tags: python, docker, pytorch, caffe

I was trying to run a script in a docker container and got this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "experiments/caffemodel2pytorch.py", line 387, in <module>
    net_param = initialize(args.caffe_proto).NetParameter()
  File "experiments/caffemodel2pytorch.py", line 35, in initialize
    mybytes = urlopen(caffe_proto).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address>
```

Part of the code is here.

```
def initialize(caffe_proto = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BVLC/caffe/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto', codegen_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp(), shadow_caffe = True):
    global caffe_pb2
    if caffe_pb2 is None:
        local_caffe_proto = os.path.join(codegen_dir, os.path.basename(caffe_proto))
        with open(local_caffe_proto, 'w') as f:
            mybytes = urlopen(caffe_proto).read()
            mystr = mybytes.decode('ascii', 'ignore')
            f.write(mystr)
            #f.write((urlopen if 'http' in caffe_proto else open)(caffe_proto).read())
        subprocess.check_call(['protoc', '--proto_path', os.path.dirname(local_caffe_proto), '--python_out', codegen_dir, local_caffe_proto])
        sys.path.insert(0, codegen_dir)
        old_pool = google.protobuf.descriptor._message.default_pool
        old_symdb = google.protobuf.symbol_database._DEFAULT
        google.protobuf.descriptor._message.default_pool = google.protobuf.descriptor_pool.DescriptorPool()
        google.protobuf.symbol_database._DEFAULT = google.protobuf.symbol_database.SymbolDatabase(pool = google.protobuf.descriptor._message.default_pool)
        import caffe_pb2 as caffe_pb2
        google.protobuf.descriptor._message.default_pool = old_pool
        google.protobuf.symbol_database._DEFAULT = old_symdb
        sys.modules[__name__ + '.proto'] = sys.modules[__name__]
        if shadow_caffe:
            sys.modules['caffe'] = sys.modules[__name__]
            sys.modules['caffe.proto'] = sys.modules[__name__]
    return caffe_pb2
```

I think it has something to do with the urlopen, but i don't know how to fix this in a docker container, any help would be appreciated, plz.

BTW, I start the container like this:

```
sudo nvidia-docker run -itv /home/ljh/mobilepose:/home/mobilepose -p 7777:8888 ufoym/deepo:all-py36-jupyter /bin/bash
```